# Force TypeScript to generate export/imports with the ".js" extension; running Node 16?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

Have a TS 4.7 library using ESM modules.

tsconfig.json:

```json
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["ES2020"], 
    "moduleResolution": "node",
```

package.json

```json
"type": "module",
```

I have a main file with only a one silly export:

index.ts

```
export { Spig } from './spig';
```

which is compiled to:

index.js

```js
export { Spig } from './spig';
//# sourceMappingURL=index.js.map
```

### Problem

When I use this library from a Node CLI program (with ESM modules enabled as well), I get the following error:

```
Cannot find module <path>/lib/spig imported from <path>/lib/index.js
```

When I **manually** add `.js` in the generated `index.js`, the issue is gone:

```js
export { Spig } from './spig.js';
```

How can I force TypeScript compiler to generate the extension, too? What am I missing here?

Comment: I assume just adding `.js` to the import is a problem?

Comment: I can't add `.js` in my typescripts, compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot omit the file extension anymore in ESM module imports. The extension should be always `.js`/`.jsx`, not `.ts`/`.tsx` for a typescript file. So, in the `index.ts` you should add the extension to `spig` export like the following and every other file imported/exported if using ESM modules.:

**index.ts**

```
export { Spig } from './spig.js';
```

Also, `moduleResolution` should be set to `Node16` or `NodeNext` so ESM modules work as expected.

As stated in the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) (enphasis by me):

Relative import paths need full extensions (e.g we have to write `import "./foo.js"` instead of `import "./foo"`).

**When a `.ts` file is compiled as an ES module, ECMAScript import/export syntax is left alone in the `.js` output**; when it’s compiled as a CommonJS module, it will produce the same output you get today under module: commonjs.

This also means paths resolve differently between `.ts` files that are ES modules and ones that are CJS modules. For example, let’s say you have the following code today:

```js
// ./foo.ts
export function helper() {
    // ...
}

// ./bar.ts
import { helper } from "./foo"; // only works in CJS
helper();
```

This code works in CommonJS modules, but will fail in ES modules because **relative import paths need to use extensions**. As a result, it will have to be rewritten to use the extension of the output of `foo.ts` - so `bar.ts` will instead have to import from `./foo.js`.

```js
// ./bar.ts
import { helper } from "./foo.js"; // works in ESM & CJS
helper();
```

This might feel a bit cumbersome at first, but TypeScript tooling like auto-imports and path completion will typically just do this for you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand what I have to do or change?

Comment: Yes, but this was not complete answer.  `"moduleResolution": "Node16"` should be set for typescript. Please update your answer for completeness

Comment: Of course. I've edited the answer with this change as needed as well.