# How to force TypeScript in Node to not require .js extension when importing ES6 modules?

Tags: node.js, typescript, es6-modules

I have a Node API set up with TypeScript working fine.

However, to import an ES6 extension, I have to include `.js` even though the file is `.ts`.

Using the `.ts` extension or leaving out the extension in the import line causes the error:

```
CustomError: Cannot find module 'C:\.....\src\models'
```

`server.ts`

```
import express from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { user } from './models.js';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3049;

app.get('/', (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
    res.send(user);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`listening on port http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

`models.ts`

```
import { IUser } from './interfaces.js';

export const user: IUser = {
    firstName: "Hendrick",
    lastName: "Denzmann",
    accessGroups: ['loggedInUsers', 'members']
};
```

I start my app with this command in `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon"
},
```

And here are my config files:

`nodemon.json`

```
{
    "watch": [""],
    "ext": "ts",
    "exec": "./node_modules/.bin/ts-node-esm src/server.ts"
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "module": "esnext",
        "outDir": "build"
    }
}
```

What do I need to change so that I can import my ES6 modules without an extension, like this: `import { user } from './models';`?

Comment: The file extensions are [mandatory](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions), otherwise you're stuck with [experimental features](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#customizing-esm-specifier-resolution-algorithm).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'll need to tell the node binary to stop requiring extensions. Currently this is done through an experimental flag, `--experimental-specifier-resolution=node`. Then you can use `ts-node` as a loader instead.

Basically, just change the `exec` part of your `nodemon.json` to this:

```json
{
  "watch": [""],
  "ext": "ts",
  "exec": "node --experimental-specifier-resolution=node --loader ts-node/esm src/server.ts"
}
```

Comment: This is too experimental and causes other issues in my application.

Comment: This is so weird, I don't need to do it with vite based application but need it for normal application

Comment: I've found success using an npm package called 'extensionless'

Comment: still, this does not remove the errors in your IDE. e.g. webstorm will still complain. just use     `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your tsconfig.json and you're good

Answer (score -2):

Most probably [ESM module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html) is enabled in the `package.json` file with the following configuration.

**package.json**

```
{
  ...
  "type": "module"
  ...
}
```

Just remove it. If it's not possible to remove it check this other answer [Force TypeScript to generate export/imports with the ".js" extension; running Node 16?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73441968/2828341)

Also change the `tsconfig.json`'s `compilerOptions` module from `esnext` to `commonjs`.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    // ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: But I want to use ES modules, not CommonJS modules. And I need to have `"type": "module"` set in my package.json since I deploy this at Heroku which needs this when it executes the transpiled JavaScript.

Comment: There is no way to use ES modules without the file extension. It's part of how it works. Check out the documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/esm-node.html

Comment: But e.g. create-react-app accomplishes this with Webpack, and Vite accomplishes this with esbuild. Surely there is some tweak or setting or hack to be able to leave it out. Or a way to use Parcel or some simple build tool like Gulp to accomplish this. It's not a blocker, it's just a non-optimal leaky abstraction: having to import non-existent .js modules when developing a TypeScript app.

Comment: Yeah... it looks totally weird importing a `.js` file instead of the `.ts` file. I don't feel comfortable either.

Comment: Do you realize that `.ts` files are not run?  They are compiled into `.js` files and that's what you actually run.

Comment: Yes, of course I realize that, but I would like to have the TypeScript programming environment that I have in e.g. React sites created with Vite or create-react-app where you don't provide the extension. There must be some kind of easy way to e.g. add the .js extension during the build process.

Comment: The way to do it is to write a "custom loader." Or you can just use an npm package that does it for you, e.g., check out `extensionless`

Comment: Nah.. you totally can enable extensionless imports.  set    `"moduleResolution": "node"` ( i know it is deprecated but still it works like I believe it should, not needing to import weird .js extensions in a pure ts project) Btw I am using tsx as a typescript runner for node and I couldn't be happier!